# Conditionally required attribute for nested object

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi

I have to validate the field based on certain conditions. I can able to validate the property which is located in side a class. But I cannot validate the nested object. Please refer my code snippet below.

**I need to make POBox property Country is required if the Student.Id is 10.**

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("Id", 10)]
    public int Class { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{

    **//// I need to validate this property based on the value property located in student class.**
    /// <summary>
    /// PO Box number is required if student id is 10
    /// </summary>
    [RequiredIf("Student.Id", 10)]
    public string POBox { get; set; }
    // POBox is required in Ethiopia
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }
    // State is required in US
    public string destination { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But country has no knowledge of student, so even if your custom attribute code could follow a dot path of Student.Id, a country doesn't link to the student that links to it. There isn't some automatic magic global registry of every student-country link that will step in and go "oh this is Canada country and that student John object links to it so the student for this country is John"..

As you have it it might be simplest to add a property Student to Country that you link up when you create a country (so country and student are linked in both directions) and another property StudentId that pulls the Id out of the Student instance linked in the Student property .. You can then RequiredIf on "StudentId", a property of the country

All this assuming the relationship of students to countries is 1:1. If your country instance is singular and many students relate to it, you'll need to rethink the strategy

Comment: Actually I just provided the sample code to ask the experts whether it is possible to add requiredif annotation on the nested object property. But my exact scenario is different.

Comment: And you have my commentary on that. Always a risk asking one question when your problem is another; you might not be able to translate the advice you received to be applicable to the actual problem